# TCP socket programming in Python -- login FTP

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ftp

I'm learning TCP socket programming and I want to create a fake ftp client -- not using any ftp library. I have searched and read many articles, but did not find a clue how to login with username and password after the connection is built..

As you can see in the following code, the socket is created and the connection to the remote host can be successfully built, but then how can I send the username and password to the server?

(I run it on my terminal and it works)

I am very new to python, could you please give me some names of library or direction that I should go? Thank you very much.

```
import socket   # For sockets
import sys       
import getpass  # Prompt the user for a password without echoing

# Starting: input host:
my_host = raw_input('myftp ')

# Build connection 
try:
    #create an AF_INET, STREAM socket (TCP)
    my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit();
print "Socket Created!"

# get IP address...
try:
    remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(my_host)
except socket.gaierror:
    #could not resolve
    print 'Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting..'
    sys.exit()
  
port = socket.getservbyname('http','tcp') # return port number
print "port: ", port

my_socket.connect((remote_ip,port))
print 'Socket connected to ' + my_host + '. The IP is ' + remote_ip
 
# Input user info
my_username = raw_input('Username: ')
my_password = getpass.getpass()
```

Comment: So... I know it's not funny to read, but you should take a look to the FTP RFC : http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/

Comment: If you have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol#Login) it should help. You're searching for the USER and PASS commands

Comment: Hi FunkySayu and Salo Thank you very much -- I think so! I'm looking at the socket's sendall() and the ftp commands now : D

Answer (score 0):

```
def CheckForLogin(target):
    try:
        server = (target,21)
        user = "USER anonymous\r\n"
        pwd = "PASS anonymous\r\n"
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.connect(server)        
        sock.recv(4096)
        sock.sendall(user.encode())
        sock.recv(4096)     
        sock.sendall(pwd.encode())
        answer = sock.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')        
        if "230" in answer:
            open('found_ftp','a').write(target+":21 anonymous:anonymous\n")            
            sock.recv(4096)            
            print(sock.recv(120000))
        elif "530" in answer:
            sock.close()
        sock.close()
    except:
        print("Login failed!\n")
        pass
```